# knative service not working with nginx image

Tags: nginx, knative, knative-serving

Do you know why nginx is not starting using Knative?

No problem using standard deployment:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
```

But using Knative service - there is issues:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-web
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

Kubectl get ksvc:

```
Unknown   RevisionMissing
```

kubectl describe revision service-web:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age                    From                 Message
  ----     ------         ----                   ----                 -------
  Warning  InternalError  4m55s (x3 over 4m55s)  revision-controller  failed to update deployment "service-webb-qb4km-deployment": Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.apps "service-web-qb4km-deployment": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there's a typo in your error message (it doubles the `b`); if not I'd look at that first.

Do you have any sort of controller or mutating webhook operating on deployments? The message that the controller can't update the deployment because there is a newer version suggests that there is some sort of racing update going on.